# Get data from a website in android

Tags: android

I developed an app in Windows phone  8/8.1, now I am trying to develop for android users. I am getting data from a website and displaying in my app. the website needs login userid,password. I successfully implemented it in C#. but I am unable to do it in java. can some guide me.

My code in C# :

```
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler, false);

            handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            handler.PreAuthenticate = true;

            Uri vceURI = new Uri("http://xxxx/default.aspx");
            var html = await client.GetStringAsync(siteURI);

            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            var viewstateNode = doc.GetElementbyId("__VIEWSTATE");
            var eventvalidationNode = doc.GetElementbyId("__EVENTVALIDATION");
            var viewstate = viewstateNode.GetAttributeValue("value", "");
            var eventvalidation = eventvalidationNode.GetAttributeValue("value", "");


            var formContent1 = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("__VIEWSTATE", viewstate), 
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventvalidation),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("txtLoginID",_username),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("txtPWD",_pswd),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("btnLogin","Go%21")
        });

            var outputDoc = await client.PostAsync("http://xxx/default.aspx", formContent1);

            html = await outputDoc.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

                            // parsing(doc);

            var studentInfoNode = doc.GetElementbyId("divStudInfo");
            var _studentinfonode1 = studentInfoNode.ChildNodes;
            var studentInfo = studentInfoNode.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes;
```

the above studentInfo object contain required data

I tried using HttpClient + HttpPost but I am ending up in null exception :(

If some ever worked on similar application can you please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you post your C# code?

Comment: java code, stack trace and indication of the null pointer exception line pls

Comment: Post the java code you tried for your app and your Logcat output when you get the error.

Comment: I made few progress. Now I am able to get HTML code of the page using following snippet.   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
   HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

   
   InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
   StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
   String line = null;
   while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
   {
       str.append(line);
   }
   in.close();
   html = str.toString();